# Windows Phone 8 - Slow image loading when source is a bound value

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, binding

I've just changed my image source in xaml from a literal to a bound value. In doing so the speed at which the image loads is noticeably slower. I'm doing this same thing in other areas and haven't noticed the same problem:

From this (displaying fast):

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" Source="/MyApp.Phone8;component/Resources/dark.png" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="10"/>
```

To this (displaying slow):

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="10 10 10 30"/>

    public SplashPage() {

        if (App.Root != null) {
            _splashViewModel = App.Root.SplashViewModel;
            DataContext = _splashViewModel;
        }

        InitializeComponent();
    }

public String Image {
        get {
                return "/MyApp.Phone8;component/Resources/dark.png";
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to fix the performance lag? This is the first time the image is displayed.

Comment: When do you bind your Image? At the beginning?

Comment: Yes, this is the very first xaml page that loads. Only the image plus some text in a grid.

Comment: In my test, I don't feel any slow displaying in data binding. Could you offer a test project? Or maybe you can check you DataContext attach timing. If you set your DataContext in Loaded event, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Datacontext is set in the constructor.